# was or were - what is the correct usage?

Tags: word-usage, plural-forms, singular

The efficiency of the companies were evaluated based on operating profit per employee (weightage-60 percent), growth in operating profit (20 percent) and balance sheet size (20 percent).

Comment: *The efficiency* is the subject of the sentence.

Comment: *Efficiency* ***was***, and *efficiencies* ***were***.

Answer (score 1):

> The efficiency of the companies **were** evaluated based on operating profit per employee (weightage-60 percent), growth in operating profit (20 percent) and balance sheet size (20 percent).

It should be:

> The **efficiency** of the companies **was** evaluated based on operating profit per employee (weightage-60 percent), growth in operating profit (20 percent) and balance sheet size (20 percent).

The verb pertains to the subject 'efficiency', and not the 'companies'.